# BehaviorSubject subscription not listening for value changes

Tags: angular, axios, angular-promise, behaviorsubject, subscriber

I am creating an angular app where I have an API service. This service calls API using axios and updates the value of BehaviorSubject as requires here is the code for that.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Post } from "../mock/post.model";
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class APIService {

    private AxiosInstance = axios.create();

    private newsList: BehaviorSubject<Post[]>;
    private startupList: BehaviorSubject<Post[]>;
    private allPosts: Post[];
    constructor() {
        this.initBS();
    }

    initBS() {
        this.newsList = new BehaviorSubject<Post[]>(null);
        this.startupList = new BehaviorSubject<Post[]>(null);
    }

    getAllPosts(): void {
        this.AxiosInstance.get(MY_API_ENDPOINT)
            .then(data => {
                const resp: Post[] = this.mapNews(data.data);
                this.allPosts = resp;
                let tempNews: Post[] = [];
                let tempStartup: Post[] = [];
                for (const post of this.allPosts) {
                    for (const cat of post.category) {
                        if (cat.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('news')) {
                            tempNews.push(post);
                        }
                        if (cat.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('startup')) {
                            tempStartup.push(post);
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.newsList.next(tempNews);
                this.startupList.next(tempStartup);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    getNewsList() {
        return this.newsList.asObservable();
    }

    getStartupList() {
        return this.startupList.asObservable();
    }
    
    mapNews(data: any[]): Post[] {
        return MAPPED_RESPONSE_TO_POST_ARRAY; // logic to convert axios response to Post array
    }

}
```

The above service is called by the constructor of home component.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../../@core/mock/post.model';
import { APIService } from '../../@core/services/API.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-editors',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  newsList: Post[];
  startupList: Post[];
  constructor(private api: APIService) {
    this.newsList = [];
    this.startupList = [];
    let i = 0;
    api.getNewsList().subscribe(
      (value) => {
        console.log('onHomeNews:');
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this.startupList);
        if (value != null) {
          for (const post of value) {
            if (i < 4) {
              this.newsList.push(post);
              i++;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('onComplete:');
    });

    i = 0;
    api.getStartupList().subscribe(
      (value) => {
        console.log('onHomeStartup:');
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this.startupList);
          for (const post of value) {
            if (i < 4) {
              this.startupList.push(post);
              i++;
            }
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('onComplete:');
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting newsList when the response comes from the API but no value is change is detected for startupList. I am getting response on tempStartup that means the API is sending data.
**Edit 1**
I have another component called startup where also I have subscribed to getStartupList(). When I switch to that component and come back to home component the startupList gets updated. Here are the logs before switching to the startup component.

```
sub-header.component.ts:86 home
home.component.ts:40 onHomeNews:
home.component.ts:41 null
home.component.ts:42 []
home.component.ts:62 onHomeStartup:
home.component.ts:63 null
home.component.ts:64 []
home.component.ts:40 onHomeNews:
home.component.ts:41 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
home.component.ts:42 []
```

Logs after switching to startup component and coming back to home component.

```
sub-header.component.ts:86 home
home.component.ts:40 onHomeNews:
home.component.ts:41 null
home.component.ts:42 []
home.component.ts:62 onHomeStartup:
home.component.ts:63 null
home.component.ts:64 []
home.component.ts:40 onHomeNews:
home.component.ts:41 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
home.component.ts:42 []
sub-header.component.ts:86 startup
sub-header.component.ts:86 home
home.component.ts:40 onHomeNews:
home.component.ts:41 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
home.component.ts:42 []
home.component.ts:62 onHomeStartup:
home.component.ts:63 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
home.component.ts:64 []
```

**P.S.** getAllPost() is called from app.component.ts so that its called as soon as the app is created.

Comment: Do you mean the `startupList` is not updated in the HTML template when new data is pushed to it?

Comment: @MichaelD Yes exactly I have used ngFor to loop over the array of objects and update the UI accordingly. Should I add that code too? Also, I tried logging the changes in the subscription of getStartupList() but didn't get any logs when the response came from API.

Comment: i hope  this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/66065612/11345235

Comment: @PiyushJain I appreciate the help. But this didn't help.

Comment: This is a pretty complex thing to debug on stackoverflow. If you could create a stackblitz it could help. Also, you can join me and some other devs on a discord server and we can walk through it together https://discord.gg/Auh7zDkd

Answer (score 0):

The Angular renderer does not know the list has been updated when `push` to the array. The underlying reference to the array hasn't changed, so it won't re-render the template.

Instead you could reassign the variable holding the array using the spread operator.

```js
export class HomeComponent {
  ...

  constructor(private api: APIService) {
    this.newsList = [];
    this.startupList = [];
    let i = 0;
    api.getNewsList().subscribe(
      (value) => {
        ...
              this.newList = [...this.newsList, post];        // <-- reassign using spread operator
        ...
      },
      ...
    );

    i = 0;
    api.getStartupList().subscribe(
        ...
            this.startupList = [...this.startupList, post];   // <-- reassign using spread operator
        ...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. The view updation is not the problem, but that on adding next value to the behavioursubject it is not getting reflected on its subscription. The thing becomes complicated as one subscription is working perfectly, for the newsList. But, for startipList changes are not getting reflected.

Comment: Strange thing happened. After your suggestion, I directly assigned (startupList = value) and now it started working. I get the updated list on view. But as I want only top 4 list items to show I did startupList.length = 4. But now the list is reduced to 4 elements on all the components across my app.