# compoent interaction with rxjs in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

i make news application with news api and i fetch data properly and but not sending data from service to component so how can send data from service to component
and component to component through rxjs

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
 
 
 @Injectable()    
 export class NewService {
   
     private pushSource = new Subject<object>();
       Country_Name;
 
     constructor(private http:HttpClient,) {
       this.messages$ = this.pushSource.asObservable()
       }    // define function for call the category
     categoryNews(category)
     {
       var categoryData = this.http.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=${category}&apiKey=********`)
          .subscribe(Data=> this.pushSource.next(Data));
     }

  news(t_h)
     {  
       console.log(t_h);      
       this.pushSource.next(t_h);
     }  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is you not import Observable, observable  that's why the problem occurred

> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { Subject, Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';
>
> @Injectable()
> export class NewService {
> messages$: Observable;
> private pushSource = new Subject();
> Country_Name;
>
> ```
> constructor(private http:HttpClient,) {  
>   this.messages$ = this.pushSource.asObservable()  
>    
> }
> ```
>
> categoryNews(category)
> {
> var categoryData = this.http.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=${category}&apiKey=*****`)
> categoryData.subscribe(Data=> this.pushSource.next(Data));
> }
> news(t_h)
> {
> console.log(t_h);
>
> ```
>   this.pushSource.next(t_h);  
> }
> ```